# expected different dimension from test_set in keras

Tags: keras

i have tried to make a simple project like "mnist",but i found error about mismatch dense

i tried to use different dataset from https://github.com/amir-saniyan/HodaDatasetReader
and tried to follow I had down before for "mnist"
but this error happend!

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train..py", line 51, in <module>
    score = network.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1102, in evaluate
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 128, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (20000, 10, 2)`

and the error is happend in this line:

```
score = network.evaluate(x_test, y_test)"
```

#### the way i define my data_Set:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from HodaDatasetReader.HodaDatasetReader import read_hoda_cdb, read_hoda_dataset
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (7,9) # Make the figures a bit bigger
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils, to_categorical
```

## load training data

```
nb_classes = 10
x_train, y_train = read_hoda_dataset(dataset_path='HodaDatasetReader/DigitDB/Train 60000.cdb',
                                images_height=32,
                                images_width=32,
                                one_hot=False,
                                reshape=True)
x_test, y_test = read_hoda_dataset(dataset_path='HodaDatasetReader/DigitDB/Test 20000.cdb',
                              images_height=32,
                              images_width=32,
                              one_hot=True,
                              reshape=False)

x_train = x_train.reshape((60000, 32 * 32))
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape((20000, 32 * 32))
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
```

#### model

```
network = Sequential()
network.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(32 * 32,)))
network.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

#### and prediction

```
network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
network.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=1000)
score = network.evaluate(x_test, y_test)###error was here :(
```

Comment: This is probably related to batch size.

Comment: i tried different numbers,please tell me what to do?
for example change it to what?

Comment: Why is the shape (20000, 10, 2)? It should be (20000, 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i found we don't need to change y-test form ,so just remove this part of code:
"y_test = to_categorical(y_test)"
and it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with y_test. You can change the code with following code, because there is difference initialization between your `x_train, y_train` and `x_test, y_test`.

```
x_test, y_test = read_hoda_dataset(dataset_path='HodaDatasetReader/DigitDB/Test 20000.cdb',
                              images_height=32,
                              images_width=32,
                              one_hot=False,
                              reshape=True)
```